# How to Add and remove attribute if found specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some list items and if I click any list item it become selected by adding class .selected
If I click outside of the list item all list item become unselected. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/21/)**

I also have one button initially disabled. I wanted to make the button active by removing **"disabled"** attribute when list items are selected.

Again if I click outside all list item should be unselected and button become disable again.
How I can do this? Any help will be appreciated.

**JS**

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
    $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".list-group-item, .load-table").length === 0) {
      $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you're missing is how to enable/disable your button and that is

```
$('.load-table').prop('disabled',false); // or true to disable
```

So just plug this in as required

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
    $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.load-table').prop('disabled',false);
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".list-group-item, .load-table").length === 0) {
      $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected'); 
        $('.load-table').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/22/

Comment: This is just perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) instead and set else condition  and to disable and enable the button use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.load-table').prop('disabled',false);
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("list-group")) {
      $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected'); 
    }
    else{
        $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected'); 
        $('.load-table').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/27/)

Answer (score 0):

Use attr() property of jquery.

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function () {
    $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    if ($("button").attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
        $("button").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".list-group-item, .load-table").length === 0) {
        $('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');


        $("button").attr("disabled", true);

    }
});
```

Above code should work. When the item is clicked then check if the button is still disabled. If it is then enable the button.

Same goes when the user click outside the list.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/28/)